# Variables not closing

Tags: javascript, variables, recursion

I am trying to do a depth-first search (DFS) of a generic tree. The goal for each node is to know its level AND the maximum number of levels beneath it.  An example tree looks like:

[image]

The DFS order should (I think) be: 1,2,3,5,6,7,4,8,9,10,11.

What I am trying to achieve is:
Node 1: Level 1, max levels beneath=4

Node 2: Level 2, max levels beneath=3

Node 3: Level 3, max levels beneath=2

...

Node 9: Level 2, max levels beneath=1

I am, so far, able to properly count the levels and max levels, but whenever I try and save them to a new object, what ultimately results is the last level/max-level combination of numbers (in this example, it would be level=3, max-level beneath=0.  I think it is not closing over the variables properly, but I must admit I can't figure out how to change it to make it work.  I assume it must be some sort of closure, but I haven't been able to adapt the other Stack answers I've found on closures.

```
 var groupIDInfo={
 BASE:[1], 1:[2,8,9], 2:[3,4], 3:[5], 4:[], 5:[6,7], 6:[], 7:[], 8:[],
  9:[10,11], 10:[], 11:[]}
var levelInfo={};
var level=0;
var longestPath=0;
var levelAndPath=[];

function detLevels(groupIDInfo, parent){

  if(!(parent in groupIDInfo)){
    console.log("parent not in array");
    return;
  }
  groupIDInfo[parent].forEach(function (child){
    level++;
    if (level>longestPath){
      longestPath=level;      
    }
    levelAndPath[0]=level;
    levelAndPath[1]=longestPath;
    levelInfo[child]=levelAndPath;

    detLevels(groupIDInfo, child);

    level--;
    //set parent longest path
    longestPath=level;
    levelInfo[parent]=levelAndPath;

  });
}
detLevels(groupIDInfo, "BASE");
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're using a single array `levelAndPath`, and pushing references to it into `levelInfo`, as opposed to pushing different arrays. (I haven't looked if there are any other errors beyond that, but this one is easily fixable by moving `var levelAndPath=[];` inside `forEach`.)

It is not about closures. It is the fact that `levelInfo[parent]=levelAndPath;` doesn't copy `levelAndPath` - it just sticks in a reference. Here's a snazzy demo, thanks to the advances in Stack Overflow snippets:

```js
let a = [1, 2, 3];
let b = [a, a, a];
a[2] = 4;
console.log(JSON.stringify(b)); // Huh? [[1,2,4],[1,2,4],[1,2,4]]?!?
console.log(b);                 // Here's what _really_ happened...
```

Comment: "Not about closures", indeed!  You are correct.  Moving the one variable inside the forEach helped immensely.  As you suspected, however, there are other errors, but those seem to be due to the logic I am using (or not using) to capture the appropriate values.  I will work at those and see if I can get this to work the way I want.  I have marked the answer as correct as you have astutely pointed out that it is not a closure issue and provided a fix for that issue.  The rest of the logic, well, I'll just pick away at it. Thanks very much for taking the time.

Comment: I've been working with this and still can't get some things to function properly. The move you suggested helped, but I'm wondering if there is still an issue with the levelInfo[parent]=levelAndPath.  LevelAndPath uses level, which changes throughout the function.  So, after one of the recursion ends, level is decremented (level--;) and then used in levelInfo[parent].  Does it inadvertently change levelInfo[child] which is assigned further up the function, before the recursive call?  If so, how can I fix that?

Comment: It does indeed. For another thing, you can't really get depth at node from its level - the two are kind of opposite. In fact, once you have the root depth, depth at node is the difference between root depth and level, so you can do it in steps, which would be much easier for you: first find level for each node (you already got this), then find the max level (easy), then calculate the depth at node.